# Definitively determine if currently running shell is bash or zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

How can I definitively determine if the currently running shell is bash or zsh?

(being able to disambiguate between additional shells is a bonus, but only bash & zsh are 100% necessary)

I've seen a few ways to supposedly do this, but they all have problems (see below).

The best I can think of is to run some syntax that will work on one and not the other, and to then check the errors / outputs to see which shell is running.  If this is the best solution, what command would be best for this test?

The simplest solution would be if every shell included a read-only parameter of the same name that identified the shell.  If this exists, however, I haven't heard of it.

Non-definitive ways to determine the currently running shell:

```sh
# default shell, not current shell
basename "${SHELL}"

# current script rather than current shell
basename "${0}"

# BASH_VERSINFO could be defined in any shell, including zsh
if [ -z "${BASH_VERSINFO+x}" ]; then
    echo 'zsh'
else
    echo 'bash'
fi

# executable could have been renamed; ps isn't a builtin
shell_name="$(ps -o comm= -p $$)"
echo "${shell_name##*[[:cntrl:][:punct:][:space:]]}"

# scripts can be sourced / run by any shell regardless of shebang
# shebang parsing
```

Comment: Posting as a comment because I'm on my phone where I can't test, but I think something like `is_zsh= ; : | is_zsh=1` should work (using the fact that in Bash, all commands in a pipeline are run in subshells and therefore can't affect the main execution environnent, whereas in Zsh, the last command in a pipeline is *not* run in subshell).

Comment: @ruakh Thanks. That seems to work. It's insane that the various shell implementors haven't yet collectively devised a standard read-only parameter for this.

Comment: @ruakh Do most other popular non-bash / non-zsh shells run the last command in the current shell (like zsh) or in a subshell (like bash)?

Comment: @ruakh : Great idea, if you know for sure that the shell must be either bash or zsh and can't be anything else. Drawback maybe is compatibility: Can we assume that future bash versions still behave in this way?

Comment: `if test -v BASH_VERSION; then echo bash; elif test -v ZSH_VERSION; then echo zsh; else echo "Unknow shell $SHELL"; fi` Ok maybe not the `else` statement but you get the idea. however `-v` fails on dash and sh and of course *csh...

Comment: @ruakh That'd yield a false positive if bash's `lastpipe` option was set.

Comment: @oguzismail Is there a better command to test this, then?  Can I easily disable the bash `lastpipe` option for a single command, like how I can set a variable for a single command?  If not, can I restrict an option setting to a single function, like the following does in zsh: `setopt localoptions …`?

Comment: @XDR I don't know. If I had to, I'd write a separate script for zsh; for it's not compatible with other shells

Comment: @oguzismail And there's no simple way to set a bash shell option just for function, other than storing the current value, changing it (or leaving it the same, depending on initial value), then setting it back?

Comment: A function defined in this fashion `f() ( commands )` can not alter the shell it's run in since `commands` are to be run in a subshell

Comment: Why does the script need to run under `bash` or `zsh` in the first place? Pick one language, or restrict your script to the intersection of the two languages. (Taken to the extreme, the second option reduces to "Write POSIX-compliant shell scripts".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from comments by @ruakh & @oguzismail, I think I have a solution.

```sh
\shopt -u lastpipe 2> /dev/null
shell_name='bash'; : | shell_name='zsh'
```

Comment: `shopt` itself isn't defined in `zsh`, so you could replace `return 1` with `{ echo zsh; return 1; }`, if you aren't concerned with an older version of `bash` being confused with `zsh`. (Since `lastpipe` wasn't added until `bash` 4.2.)

Comment: @chepner: I'd like to cover as many versions of zsh & bash as possible from current back as far as I can easily go.  `shopt` could be provided by an external command, or user-defined function, so I shouldn't completely rely on it not existing.  Is there any way to specify that I only want to run a builtin `shopt` for bash (rather than a user override), and that I want to try to run `shopt` as a builtin in zsh (which will necessarily fail)?

Comment: @chepner My code now uses `builtin`, which seems to work on zsh 5.8, bash 5.0.16(1)-release & bash 3.2.57(1)-release.  Is there any way I can change this to a one-liner?

Comment: @ruakh: I've only recently started to write scripts for bash & zsh. I fixed the lastpipe 
 issue with your suggestion, fixed issues with stderr output, and fixed issues with non-builtins possibly being run.  I kept your original suggestion because I wasn't sure if I could remove it.  I've tested a shorter command that seems to work for both zsh & bash, and I've updated the answer.  If you have a shorter or better version, or know of other issues that must be fixed, please let me know.

Answer (score 8):

On $ prompt, run:

```
echo $0
```

but you can't use `$0` within a script, as `$0` will become the `script's name` itself.

To **find the current shell** (let's say BASH) if shebang / magic number executable was `#!/bin/bash` **within** a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script is: $0 running using $$ PID"
echo "Current shell used within the script is: `readlink /proc/$$/exe`"

script_shell="$(readlink /proc/$$/exe | sed "s/.*\///")"

echo -e "\nSHELL is = ${script_shell}\n" 

if [[ "${script_shell}" == "bash" ]]
then
    echo -e "\nI'm BASH\n"
fi
```

Outputs:

```
Script is: /tmp/2.sh running using 9808 PID
Current shell used within the script is: /usr/bin/bash

SHELL is = bash

I'm BASH
```

This will work, if shebang was: `#!/bin/zsh` (as well).

Then, you'll get the output for SHELL:

```
SHELL is = zsh
```

Comment: You can source a file with a shebang from a different shell, or run the file as an argument to a different shell.  Shebang parsing just tells you what the shebang is, not what's running the file.

Comment: this doesn't work for busybox: `sh 2.sh`, `ash 2.sh`, `hush 2.sh` all will return `SHELL is = busybox.nosuid`, `Current shell used within the script is: /bin/busybox.nosuid`

Comment: and in other shells it'll still be unreliable because names can easily be changed. For example sh is commonly a symlink to dash or bash on many distros

Answer (score 7):

While there is no 100% foolproof way to achieve it, it might help to do a

```
echo $BASH_VERSINFO
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

Both are shell variables (not environment variables), which are set by the respective shell. In the respective other shell, they are empty.

Of course, if someone on purpose creates a variable of this name, or exports such a variable and then creates a subshell of the different kind, i.e.

```
# We are in a non-bash here (ksh, zsh, dash, ...)
export BASH_VERSINFO=5
zsh  # the new zah subshell will see BASH_VERSION even though it is zsh
```

this approach will fail; but I think if someone is really doing such a thing, he wants to sabotage your code on purpose.

Comment: This is almost equivalent to the if condition in my list of methodologies that don't work definitively.  `BASH_VERSINFO` is read-only in bash, whereas `BASH_VERSION` is not, so I used `BASH_VERSINFO` as it cannot be unset in bash.

Comment: @XDR: This is correct. BASH_VERSION and BASH_VERSINFO can not be redefined in bash, and undefines them before calling a child process. For completeness: zsh does not provide this protection for ZSH_VERSION. I will adapt my response accordingly.

Comment: My previous comment is correct. I was just able to change the value for `BASH_VERSION` in both bash 5.2.15(1)-release (from homebrew) & 3.2.57(1)-release (from macOS) on macOS 12.6.5. I was not able to change `BASH_VERSINFO` on either version.

Comment: @XDR : Indeed I could verify this. Only `BASH_VERSINFO` has this property. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for most Linux systems:

```
cat /proc/$$/comm
```

Quick and easy.

Comment: Not every Unix-like system has a procfs.

Comment: Then I go for `most Linux systems` ;)